# Django + Javascript - Ejecutar javascript sólo si valor del ORM de Django no es None

Tags: javascript, django

¿Cómo ejecutar las dos lineas javascript sólo si los valores del ORM de Django no son None?
(Ya que si algún valor es None, no ejecuta nada).

```
{% for station in stations5 %}

if {{ station.latitud }} != "None"{
    latlngs.push(new L.LatLng({{ station.latitud }},{{ station.longitud }}));
    latlngs.push(new L.LatLng({{ station.punto_comunicacion.latitud}},{{ station.punto_comunicacion.longitud}}));
}

{% endfor %}
```

¿Y si debo comprovar que ninguno de los 4 valores sea None?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta parte te debería dar error (por cierto te olvidaste de poner los paréntesis, lo cual dará otro error de sintaxis):

```
if {{ station.latitud }} != "None"{
...
```

Ya que JavaScrip "interpreta" que el valor de `{{ station.latitud }}` es una variable:

```
(index):17 Uncaught ReferenceError: None is not defined
```

Entonces deberías hacerlo así:

```
if ("{{ station.latitud }}" != "None") {
...
```

De esta manera funcionara y obtendrás el comportamiento deseado.

Por otra parte otra forma de hacerlo seria validar el valor de `station.latitud` con el *template tag* `if`:

> ```
> {% if station.latitud != None %}
>     console.log('Hola! :)')
> {% endif %}
> ```
>
> Pero podrías hacer lo siguiente:
>
> ```
> {% if station.latitud %}
>     console.log('Hola! :)')
> {% endif %}
> ```
>
> Si es `None`, no entrara al `if`. Esto ya es de python:
>
> ```
> >>> x = None
> >>> if x:
> ...     print('HOLA')
> ... else:
> ...     print(':(')
> ... 
> :(
> >>>
> ```

En mi opinión cualquiera de las dos formas es valida.

---

Pero lo que yo te recomiendo, es que hagas peticiones AJAX al backend y que tu vista retorne un `JsonResponse` con los datos serializados a JSON, y en base a los datos hagas las respectivas validaciones, etc. Me parece una forma mas limpia de hacerlo.

Espero haberte ayudado.